# Inject dependencies to web api controller without parameterless constructor(Ninject

Tags: asp.net-web-api, ninject

I have two Web API controllers to which I want to inject dependencies into using Ninject, like this:

```
public ProductsController(IProductRepository repository) {
    _repository = repository;
}
```

I'm setting the `DependencyResolver` like this:

```
config.DependencyResolver = new NinjectDependencyResolver(ninjectKernel);
```

Everything works fine for one controller without a parameterless constructor, but for another controller it's not working without a parameterless constructor.

Can anyone help me out to understand why it's not working?

I have followed this link implement di using ninject from stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22788538/cannot-inject-dependencies-using-ninject-into-asp-net-web-api-controller-called)

Comment: Are you injecting same IProductRepository to another controller or different one? Also make sure that they inherit same base class.